# Galois extension of real subfield is of degree at most $2$?

Tags: galois-theory

I am given that $F$ is a subfield of $\mathbb R$, and $K=F(\sqrt[n]{a})$, where $a\in F$ is such that it has a real $n$th root. I want to show that , if $L$ is a Galois extension of $F$ contained in $K$, then its degree over $F$ is at most $2$.

Now, I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that the $d$th roots of unity are real only when $d=1$ or $2$, but of course $L$ can be a field other than the splitting field of $x^d-a$. So I'm assuming I have to show that $L$ must contain the $[L:F]th$ roots of unity, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Could I have some hints?

Comment: $F=\mathbb{Q}$, $n=3$, $a=2$, and $L=K$ seem to comprise a counterexample.  (If you meant strict containment, $n=6$ and $L = F[\sqrt[3]{2}]$.)

Comment: @EricTowers, if $F = \mathbb{Q}$ and $L = F[\sqrt[3]{2}]$, then $L/F$ is not Galois.  One way to see this is because it is not a splitting field of the minimal polynomial $f(x) = x^3 - 2$.

Comment: @KajHansen:  Yes.  Why is that?

Comment: Because it doesn't contain $\omega\sqrt[3]{2}$, where $\omega$ is a primitive $3$rd root of unity.

Comment: Hmm, I found this: http://planetmath.org/node/40163

but I'm not sure why $L'=F'(\sqrt[n]{\beta})$ implies that $L=F(\sqrt[n]{\beta})$.

Comment: I think you want to argue this way: Let $N$ be a normal closure of $K$, so $N$ is $K$ adjoin an $n$th root of unity. Then you know the Galois group of $N$ over $K$, and you know the Galois group of $N$ over $F$, and the group of $N$ over $L$ has to be a normal subgroup of the group of $N$ over $F$, containing the group of $N$ over $K$. A little group theory may finish things off.

Comment: Rudely posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/171917/galois-subfields-of-real-radical-extensions-are-at-most-quadratic, with no notice to either site.

Comment: Hmm, so I think $Gal(N/K)=Aut(C_n)$, $Gal(N/F)=C_n\rtimes Aut(C_n)$, so I want to show that the only normal subgroups of the latter containing the former are of index $1$ or $2$?

Comment: The link to `planetmath.org` in a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1724874) above is broken. I'm also unable to find any snapshot saved on the Wayback Machine. Perhaps the content has been moved here on PlanetMath: [Galois subfields of real radical extensions are at most quadratic](https://planetmath.org/galoissubfieldsofrealradicalextensionsareatmostquadratic)