# Normal closure of the nonnormal factor of Holomorph of a Cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, normal-subgroups, holomorph

Let $C_n$ be the cyclic group of order $n$. Then, we can consider the holomorph $G=C_n\rtimes Aut(C_n)$. let $H$ be such that $Aut(C_n)\leq H\trianglelefteq G$. Is it necessarily the case that $H$ is of index $1$ or $2$ in $G$.

I'm asking because this came up because of this question: [Galois extension of real subfield is of degree at most $2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835656/galois-extension-of-real-subfield-is-of-degree-at-most-2?noredirect=1#comment1725549_835656)

Comment: Really (mind the pun :-)) neat how you came to transpose a Galois theoretic question to a purely group theoretic one! +1 from me!

Comment: I'm not sure if my translation is entirely correct, since the Galois group may not be the full holomorph, but thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Let $G = C_n \rtimes A$ with $A = {\rm Aut}(C_n)$ and $C_n = \langle g \rangle$. Since there exists $a \in A$ with $a^{-1}ga=g^{-1}$, we have $g^2 \in [A, C_n]$, and $A \le H \unlhd G$ implies $[A,C_n] \le H$, so $\langle g^2, A \rangle \le H$ and $|G:\langle g^2, A \rangle| \le 2$.

Comment: Cool. Does this in fact prove that any subgroup is of index $1$ or $2$? I don't think you used that it was a normal subgroup...

Comment: I used $H \unlhd G$ to justify $[A,C_n] \le H$. Note that $|G:A|=n$.

Comment: Oh, I see. I guess it's because quotienting out by $H$ gives an abelian group, so the commutator must be contained in it?