# A reference/proof request for a result on real radical extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I am looking for an English reference or a proof of the following result due to Holder:

"Let $ f(x) $ be an irreducible polynomial over a real field $ K $. If all the roots of $ f(x) $ are real and expressible by real radicals (in the sense that they lie in some real radical extension of $ K $), then the Galois group of $ f $ over $ K $ is a $ 2 $-group." (quoted verbatim from [this article](https://www.impan.pl/download/pdf/aa107-4-6).)

In the linked article, there is a reference, but it is German. I have found [a page on this result](http://planetmath.org/proofofcasusirreducibilisforrealfields) on planetmath, but their argument depends on [this proof](http://planetmath.org/node/40163), where I do not see how $ L' = F'(\sqrt[n]{\beta}) $ implies that $ L = F(\sqrt[n]{\beta}) $, or even that $ \beta \in F $ in the first place.

I would appreciate it if someone provided an English reference for this result, or even better, posted a proof sketch as an answer.

Note: The planetmath references have made a previous appearance on the site in the comments section of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835656/galois-extension-of-real-subfield-is-of-degree-at-most-2), but Gerry Myerson's proof sketch is extremely lacking. (I do not see how to make his argument work, concretely.)

Comment: This is Theorem 22.14 in Martin Isaacs' *Algebra: A Graduate Course*. The proof, however, it too long to be contained in this margin :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a proof of this statement, so I am posting it as an answer for the sake of completion.

The key idea of the proof is to reduce to the case where the splitting field of $ f $ has prime degree, then use the following lemma:

**Lemma.** Let $ L/K $ be a Galois extension of real fields with odd prime degree $ p $. Then, $ L $ is contained in no real radical extension of $ K $.

**Proof.** Let $ \alpha \in \mathbb R $ such that $ \alpha^m \in K $ and $ \alpha \notin K $. Since any real radical extension is obtained by successively adjoining prime radicals, we may assume that $ m $ is prime for our argument. If $ \alpha \in L $, then all roots of $ X^m - \alpha^m $ are in $ L $ by normality, thus so are all of the $ m $th roots of unity. Since $ L $ is real, this implies $ m = 2 $, a contradiction since $ 2 $ does not divide the odd prime $ p = [L : K] $.

Thus, $ \alpha \notin L $. It follows that no root of $ X^m - \alpha^m $ can be contained in $ L $ by normality, and thus the polynomial is irreducible in $ L[X] $. Hence $ [L(\alpha) : L] = [K(\alpha) : K] = m $, and by the tower law it follows that $ [L:K] = [L(\alpha) : K(\alpha)] = p $. Thus, for any (finite) real radical extension $ M/K $, we have $ [LM : KM] = p \neq 1 $, which implies $ L \not\subset KM $. QED.

Now, let $ L/K $ be the splitting field of $ f \in K[X] $, with degree not a power of $ 2 $. The degree is then divisible by an odd prime $ p $, and $ G = \textrm{Gal}(L/K) $ contains an element $ \sigma $ of order $ p $. We may assume that $ \sigma(\alpha) \neq \alpha $ for any particular $ f(\alpha) = 0 $ by conjugating by an element of $ G $ if necessary. ($ f $ is irreducible, thus $ G $ acts transitively on its roots.) Looking at the fixed field $ M $ of $ \langle \sigma \rangle $, we find that $ L/M $ is a Galois extension of real fields with odd prime degree $ p $, and we have $ L = M(\alpha) $. By the lemma, $ L $ is contained in no real radical extension of $ M $, thus neither is $ \alpha $. Since $ K \subset M $, this is also the case for real radical extensions of $ K $, and the result follows.

Comment: May I ask why "the polynomial is irreducible in $L[x]$" given "$\alpha \notin L$"? It doesn't seems to be obvious.

Comment: This is a standard result about radical extensions; you can find it in Kaplansky's field theory book, for example.