# Is this a radical extension

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I am trying to work out whether the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha )/\mathbb{Q}$ is radical where $\alpha =\cos (\pi /7)$. I know that $\omega +1/\omega =2\cos (\pi/7 )$ where $\omega = \exp (2\pi i/7)$ and that $\mathbb{Q}(\omega )/\mathbb{Q}$ is a radical extension since $\omega $ is a root of $x^7-1 \in \mathbb{Q}[x] $.

I suspect it is actually a radical extension but can't see a way to show it?

Comment: $\mathbb Q(\alpha)=\mathbb Q(\omega)\cap\mathbb R$

Comment: How can we use this?

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2055667/a-reference-proof-request-for-a-result-on-real-radical-extensions/2058306#2058306